# Javascript use list from model

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc

Can somebody help me
this is my code:

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < @Model.BegrotingsPosten.Count; i++){
    var percentage = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.BegrotingsPosten[i].BelastingsPercentage))';
    var berekening = (valueBelastingen / 100) * percentage;
    var afgerond = (Math.round(berekening * 100) / 100);
    $('.euro').eq(i).text(afgerond);
}
```

The `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.BegrotingsPost[i].BelastingsPercentage));`
does not work and generates the following error

> The name i does not exist in the current context`.

If I use`@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.BegrotingsPost[1].BelastingsPercentage));` it does work, but I have to loop

Answer (score 2):

`@Html.Raw()` is razor code and is evaluated on the server before its been sent to the view. You `i` is a javascript variable which does not even exist at that point.

You can store the whole collection in a javascript array, and then loop through it in the script

```
var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.BegrotingsPosten));
for (var i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++) {
    var percentage = data[i].BelastingsPercentage;
    ....
}
```

Note, If your only using the one property of your collection, you may want to consider a linq `.Select()` to return just a collection of that properties values.

Comment: Yep, that'd be a better way of doing it. I was purely looking at the syntax. Time for a coffee I think...

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting out the usage of i to another var, so change

```
var percentage = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.BegrotingsPosten[i].BelastingsPercentage))';
```

to

```
var percent = @Model.BegrotingsPosten[i].BelastingsPercentage;
var percentage = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(percentage))';
```